# Debian on Lenovo Flex 5?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, system-installation, debian-installer, debian-cd

Im planning to buy this laptop off ebay:
 https://www.ebay.com/itm/Lenovo-Flex-5-2-IN-1-14-FHD-Touch-8th-Gen-i7-8550U-8GB-512GB-SSD-Webcam-Win10/113737155372?hash=item1a7b43432c:g:MW8AAOSwpmhbu0vQ

Great price, great specs, great touchscreen!

Upon further inspection, I saw in the description of the product that the model was a "Lenovo flex 5". So I went up online to search about debian support for that specific model. Heres what I found:

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Other-Linux-Discussions/Flex-5-Linux-Support/td-p/3704110

The only thing I could find were similar articles like the one above, which pretty much all talked about multi-boot with windows and ubuntu, notably.

I also saw some posts talking about OpenSUSE but im not interested in that distro.

**I want to run Debian**. No multi-boot, just plain Debian (Stable release) on an SSD.

Has anyone experienced installing Debian on that type of laptop? If you did, what did you had to do to make it work? Does the touchscreen, wifi, etc works out of the box?

Thanks alot, and sorry if I posted in the wrong website.

Ps: There isn't  lots of testimonies of people being able to run Linux distros on that laptop, so even if you made another distro work on there, please let me know!

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

The WiFi Driver and the touchscreen driver SHOULD work automatically. I don’t know how it’d like the hybrid drive system as mine is a 1 drive system. To boot into a debian build, create a live boot of what ever version you’d like. Use this link to help you out installing the ISO file on the drive and make the ISO file live: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-the-easy-way/amp/

After you made the ISO file live, shut down your target system, and open BIOS. The should be a ‘Boot Order’ tab or something similar. Make sure ALL USB instances are at the top. Save and restart. It should boot into Linux. From there there should be a thing within Linux to install into the internal disk. Do that then it’ll restart the system and when it does, unplug the drive so It boots internally. It’s going to be different on each BIOS and version of Linux you get but this should be quite close. Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the reply! Theres a misunderstanding tho, my one and only drive is an SSD, mine doesnt have an HDD.

Comment: As long as the computer’s specs support the version of Linux you are putting on it ie Linux Mint, there should be no issues running it. My Debian build of Mint is on a 2.5GHz 7 year old laptop, so I’d assume that laptop will run fine. @keanu_reeves

Comment: Big thanks to you Trevor, I will post back when I acquire the laptop :)

Comment: @keanu_reeves No problem